# which library use for TcxDataRecordHandle in delphi10.1

Tags: delphi

when i build project i found error :- E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'TcxDataRecordHandle' 
please tell me which library name add in **uses** for TcxDataRecordHandle in delphi10.1

Comment: new question :-  dxSideBar: TdxNavBar; dxSideBar.LoadFromRegistry('\Software\Entity\Flextend\1.0\Layout'); throw exception

Comment: "new question:- ...".  If you have a new question, post it as a new question, not as a change to this one, which has already been answered.

Answer (score 3):

`TcxDataRecordHandle` is declared in the unit `cxCustomData` which you should find in the Sources folder below the ExpressDataController folder in your Devex install.

Btw, you could have answered this yourself by going to `Search | Find in files` in the IDE and specifying the top level folder of your Devex in the `Directories` box of the pop-up.

Comment: in delphi 10.1 cxCustomData add in uses for TcxDataRecordHandle ?

Comment: Yes, add `cxCustomData.Pas` to the Uses list of the unit where the compiler produces the error message you quoted.

Comment: @MartynA The file names is `cxCustomData.Pas` but the unit name is `cxCustomData`, right? I have edited accordingly.

Comment: @ChetanBhatt:  I noticed that you cancelled your acceptance of my answer earlier today.  That's your choice obviously, but do you now believe the answer to be wrong, or what?